# Corrplot: Not printing every text label

Tags: r, r-corrplot

I am using the example from their vignette, but in reality, my correlation matrix is much larger so that the text labels are not legible on the plot. My desire is not to print every text label on the correlogram.

```
M <- cor(mtcars)
corrplot(M, diag = FALSE, method = "ellipse", type = "upper", tl.col = "black")
```

[image]

Is there a way to not to print every text label in the plot? I want to print every other label.

Alternatively, in order to read the plot, I want to use groups of the variables as the unique text label instead. From clustering, I found that there may be 3 groups in the data.

```
#Reorder data collected in mtcars in this way: 
mtcars2 <- mtcars[ , c("carb", "wt", "hp", "cyl", "disp", 
            "qsec", "vs",
            "mpg", "drat", "am", "gear")
            ]
#Let's say I have the following groups corresponding to these variables
groups <- c(rep("Engine", 5), rep("Speed", 2), rep("Fuel", 4) )
R <- cor(mtcars2)
colnames(R) <- groups
```

I would like to print, uniquely, these group names on the top portion of corrogram. Now, they are printed for every variable. So again, can I just print the group name once ("Engine", "Speed", "Fuel") for the set of variables?

```
corrplot(R, diag = FALSE, method = "ellipse", type = "upper", tl.col = "black")
```

[image]

In reality, the correlation plot that I am working with more looks like this.

```
set.seed(234)
A <- matrix(rnorm(1e+05), ncol = 100, dimnames = list(NULL, paste0("VeryLongName", 1:100)))
corrplot(cor(A), diag = FALSE, method = "ellipse", type = "upper")
```

[image]

The option `tl.cex = 0.5` does work, but I prefer to have larger and fewer labels.

In conclusion, I want to adjust `corrplot()` to (1) print every other label or (2) print groups uniquely on the axes.

This work was done using  **corrplot** version 0.84.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe include empty strings in `groups`

```
require(corrplot)
#Reorder data collected in mtcars in this way: 
mtcars2 <- mtcars[ , c("carb", "wt", "hp", "cyl", "disp", 
                       "qsec", "vs",
                       "mpg", "drat", "am", "gear")
                   ]
#Let's say I have the following groups corresponding to these variables
groups <- c("","Engine",rep("", 3), "Speed","", "Fuel",rep("", 3) )
rows <- c("Engine","",rep("", 3), "Speed","", "Fuel",rep("", 3) )

R <- cor(mtcars2)
colnames(R) <- groups 
rownames(R) <- rows
corrplot(R, diag = FALSE, method = "ellipse", type = "upper", tl.col = "black")
```

[image]